# How to write a function in python, given a list of terms and a value x of a derivative, that returns the value of the derivative at that point

Tags: function, loops, filter, tuples, derivative

Each term is a single tuple, for instance 2x^3 + 7x is (2,3), (7,1)
The derivative is (6,2), (7,0)

When there is a constant the constant has to be removed. For instance (2,4), (13,0) would return only (2,4).

Here is the code to find that derivative and filter out any constants, such as (13,0)

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):
    return [(term[0] * term[1], term[1] - 1)
           for i, term in enumerate(function_terms)
               if term[0] * term[1] != 0]
```

Okay, now to return the value of a derivative at a given point when provided the x value I wrote

```
def derivative_at(function_terms, x):
    filtered = list(filter(find_derivative, function_terms))
    

    new_value = filtered[0]* x, * [1]
    return new_value

find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven) # [(6, 1)]
derivative_at(three_x_squared_minus_eleven, 2) # 12
```

Here's where I'm given a TypeError

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5fd5c2308a87> in <module>
      1 find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven) # [(6, 1)]
----> 2 derivative_at(three_x_squared_minus_eleven, 2) # 12

<ipython-input-11-bc3316259675> in derivative_at(terms, x)
      9 def derivative_at(terms, x):
     10 
---> 11     filtered = list(map(find_derivative, terms))
     12     return filtered
     13 

<ipython-input-4-48549a955063> in find_derivative(function_terms)
      3 def find_derivative(function_terms):
      4     return [(term[0] * term[1], term[1] - 1)
----> 5            for i, term in enumerate(function_terms)
      6                if term[0] * term[1] != 0]

<ipython-input-4-48549a955063> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4     return [(term[0] * term[1], term[1] - 1)
      5            for i, term in enumerate(function_terms)
----> 6                if term[0] * term[1] != 0]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making things too complicated.
The function, find_derivative(), that's used to filter out any constants is applied at the bottom of the code:

```
   find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven)
```

This code filters out any constants in the terms.

After that I used a combination of two user-defined functions:

```
def term_output(term, x):
    a =  term[0]
    b =  term[1] 
    x = x
    result =  a * x * b
    return result
    

def derivative_at(list_of_terms, x):
    outputs = list(map(lambda term: term_output(term, x), list_of_terms))
    return sum(outputs)

find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven) # ([6,1])
derivative_at(three_x_squared_minus_eleven, 2) # 12
```

Derivative_at() is passed the now-filtered three_x_squared_minus_eleven argument and returns our answer, 12.